# How to remove error "Unresolved reference text" in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to create a basic android project,but i am getting a constant error "Unresolved reference text".How to resolve it?

```
package com.example.shashank.simpson2

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import com.example.shashank.simpson2.R.id.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}


 fun change(view: View)
     {

        val x=Simpson(nameText.text.toString(), Integer.parseInt(ageText.text.toString()), jobText.text.toString())
textView.text="Name "+x.name+"Age "+x.age+"Job "+x.job
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve here is to reference the view by its id in your kotlin code. You should check if you've added all the necessary plugins and implementations in your gradle script. [This](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) link thoroughly explains your problem's solution.